# Selenium test in Internet Explorer in InPrivate mode

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there any way how to run Selenium automation test in Internet Explorer 9 in InPrivate mode with IEDriverServer? 
I need to test 2 (two) testcases:
1. browser is closed. Open one window of IE InPrivate mode. Run test.
2. browser is opened in normal mode. Open new window of IE InPrivate mode. Run test.

How should JAVA code look for this tests?
Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
public void openBrowserInPrivacyMode(boolean isBrowserActive) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "path/to/IEDriverServer_x32.exe"); 
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();  
    capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.FORCE_CREATE_PROCESS, true);  
    сapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_SWITCHES, "-private");
    InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```

Answer (score 1):

@Roman's solution [is now deprecated](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/ie/InternetExplorerOptions.html).

The new way to do this is as follows:

```
InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
ieOptions.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.FORCE_CREATE_PROCESS, true);
ieOptions.addCommandSwitches("-private");
InternetExplorerDriver driver = InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions));
```

Also, I had problems doing this, until I set a [TabProcGrowth](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2716529/32-bit-browser-applications-may-not-work-as-expected-in-internet-explo) registry value. Before doing this I got the following exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer.
Unable to use CreateProcess() API. To use CreateProcess() with Internet Explorer 8 or higher,
the value of registry setting in
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\TabProcGrowth must be '0'.
```

I had this with happening with Windows 10 and Selenium 3.14. Curiously enough, setting the TabProcGrowth value also [fixed this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985300/selenium-webdriver-typing-very-slow-in-text-field-on-ie-browser) for me.