# How to run Explorer independently with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to use IE using the selenium module in python.

I want to log in with different login IDs in multiple IE windows, but the login information in IE windows is shared with each other, so independent login is not possible.

I am using selenium version is 3.6 and the explorer version is 11.

How can I fix it?

For example, when I log in to Google email in the first explorer window, when the second explorer window is turned on, I am already logged in to the Google email.

I want to log in to the same site with a different ID at the same time.

```
IE_1 =  ID_1 
IE_2 =  ID_2
IE_3 =  ID_3
....
```

Comment: Try using [private mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064512/selenium-test-in-internet-explorer-in-inprivate-mode) for the browsers

Answer (score 0):

**You can achieve separate logins by running the browser in "private" mode.**
This is not specific to IE. You can do this in Chrome Firefox, and other browsers as well.

### **1. IE in private mode**

From the [docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/driver_idiosyncrasies/driver_specific_capabilities/#ie-command-line-options), you can set "IE Command-Line Options".

> Example below is directly from the documentation.
> **I have NOT tested the below code myself**
> as I don't have IE in my environment.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.IeOptions()
options.add_argument('-private')
options.force_create_process_api = True
driver = webdriver.Ie(options=options) # MIGHT WANT TO CHANGE

# Navigate to url
driver.get("http://www.google.com")

driver.quit()
```

If you don't have the $PATH set for IE, try this:

```py
driver = webdriver.ie(executable_path="<YOUR_IE_PATH>", 
                      options=options)
```

### **2. Chrome in private mode**

> For Chrome, I can confirm it is valid working code. It's a simplified version of what I use myself.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path="<YOUR_CHROME_DRIVER_PATH>", 
    chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://google.com')
```

For the full list of acceptable "chrome_options", you can check out the [reference](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#incognito). This link may not look "official", but it's actually referenced from the [Chromedriver website](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities) (under "Recognized Capabilities" - "ChromeOptions object" - "args"), so we can safely rely on this doc.